# Find value in Dictionary<int,List<int>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary with int key and List value

I would like to find out if the key or values contains a specific integer and get the related key for it.

Example:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> removableStuff = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

removableStuff.Add(1, new List<int> {1});
removableStuff.Add(3, new List<int> {9,33,35});
removableStuff.Add(2, new List<int> {1,65,32,3});
```

I would like to find the number 3. 
Since the number 3 can be found as key and value, the output would be: 3, 2.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you just looking for the `.Where()` and `.Select()` methods on your `removableStuff` variable?

Comment: Try following : int[] key = removableStuff.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(3)).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();

Comment: Getting the key is trivial.  Wasn't worth posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar method to Tobias' answer is to use `Contains` instead of `Any(Equals)`:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> removableStuff = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>
{
    {1, new List<int> {1}},
    {3, new List<int> {9, 33, 35}},
    {2, new List<int> {1, 65, 32, 3}}
};

int find = 3;

var matches = removableStuff.Where(item => item.Key == find || item.Value.Contains(find));

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{match.Key}: {string.Join(", ", match.Value)}");
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This should yield the desired result:

```
var num = 3;
var keys = removableStuff.Where(i => i.Key.Equals(num) || i.Value.Any(num.Equals))
                         .Select(i => i.Key);
```

You can optionally call `.ToList()` after the `.Select()`, if you don't want to deal with an Enumerable.

The `i.Value.Any(num.Equals)` can also be simplified to `i.Value.Contains(num)`, but when I use Linq I like to use `Any` for that sort of stuff too. (Just personal preference)

Nonetheless this is very basic Linq and I'm sure you would've found your answer prior to asking, if you would've looked.

Comment: Yes it's incredibly simple Linq. But to be fair to OP, Linq is pretty strange and intimidating to someone not familiar with it.

Comment: I find it amazing that my answer with 5 Upvotes isn't accepted as the answer, whilst one with 0 Upvotes that ignored the part where OP said he only wanted to find the keys and is essentially just a copy of my query, gets accepted as the answer.